# Existence of saddle points under a $C^0$-perturbation of a continuous function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and has a strict maximum point  $a$ and strict minimum point $b$. Define $g(x,y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $h_\varepsilon(x,y)$ be a family of continuous functions which converge to 0 uniformly about $x,y$ as $\varepsilon\to 0$. Clearly, $(a,a)$ is a strict maximum point of $g$ and for any $\varepsilon$ small, $g+h_\varepsilon$ has a maximum point $(x_\varepsilon, y_\varepsilon)$ and $\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}x_\varepsilon=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}y_\varepsilon=a$.

Similarly, $(a,b)$ is a saddle point of $g$. My question is, for any $\varepsilon$ small, does $g+h_\varepsilon$ have a saddle point $(x_\varepsilon, y_\varepsilon)$ and $\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}x_\varepsilon=a, \lim_{\varepsilon\to0}y_\varepsilon=b$? If not, then can we add some condition to make this true?

Comment: How do you define a saddle point? Also, how do you define a strict maximum/minimum? E.g., does $\cos \dfrac{2 \pi  x^2}{x^2+1}$ have a strict maximum point?

Comment: A strict local maximum point means that it is the unique maximum point in a neighborhood of this point. In your example, x=0 is a strict local maximum point, or a strict maximum. Saddle point means it is a critical point, but not a maximum or minimum point. What I want to know is, whether a perturbation of a continuous function f has a critical point in a neighborhood of a critical point of f.